# ProviderData empty when using Anonymous Login with Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

As the title says, ProviderData turns out empty when using Anonymous Login with Firebase (Unity SDK 6.14.1).

First off, I'm using this to create/login with an anon user:

```
 Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
 auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
 {
     //this succeeds

     [insert Code1 you see below here]
 }
```

Then, I linked this account with Facebook using (Code1):

```
var credential = Firebase.Auth.FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString);
auth.CurrentUser.LinkWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task2 => 
{
   //this succeeds as well
}
```

However, `task2.Result` (which is a `FirebaseUser`-object) does for example not contain DisplayName and other info. Also now to the actual question:

When I now restart the app and invoke `auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync()` again, should I expect the response (`task.Result`) to contain ProviderData field to know what providers this user has linked? Because right now, if I login the user upon startup as I just described, the ProviderData is empty in Unity Editor and only returns Firebase on Android device.

I'm having a hard time understanding if this is intended behaviour and I should try to login using Facebook instead of keep login in anonymously? But if that's the case, I have to manually save if user connected to Facebook which seems very wrong.

I found this bug report which seems to be same/similar issue, but was resolved long time ago: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/467

Can someone tell me if I'm taking the wrong approach here or if this is indeed a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that once you've called:

```
auth.CurrentUser.LinkWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task2 => 
{
   //Insert Code 2. here
}
```

You would also need to call (Code 2.):

```
 auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWithOnMainThread((task) =>
 {
     //succeed
 });
```

Simply linking does not actually log you in, it only links you on the backend. This makes sense when you consider having multiple providers, but since I only had one it felt logical that one would auto-login together with the linking-process.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is, a FirebaseUser should have multiple [PoviderDatas (as an enumerable)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-user#providerdata). Are you saying that the field `ProviderData` is `null`, that you have an array of multiple `null` values, or that the first one is `null`?

My second question and possibly an answer, which I apologize if this feels a little patronizing but I want to be thorough:
are you calling `auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync()` every time the game runs or only if `auth.CurrentUser == null`?

[`auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/anonymous-auth) will always create a new user even if they're already signed in (this is not tied into any device identifier, so once you log out of an anonymous user you can never log in as them again). There's a chance that this could be messing with your testing if you aren't accounting for it, but otherwise I apologize if this isn't new information!

--Patrick

Comment: Thanks for your response! 

The ProviderData is an empty array in Unity Editor and on Android device only has Count == 1 and the ProviderId inside that is "firebase".

I am calling auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync() every time the game runs, is this wrong flow? This seems (at least in editor) to just login existing user and not create a new one.
I tried _not_ calling it, but CurrentUser still has an empty array of ProviderData, do I need to manually call SignInWithCredential on every startup and if it succeed just assume they had connected Facebook and if it fail..they didnt?

Comment: Generally you should call `auth.CurrentUser` before doing anything with authentication ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user ). The SDK should be smart enough to persist this (even on the Desktop - although you may need approve Keychain stuff on MacOS). If that returns null _then_ you need to try to sign in. I believe that for safety reasons, it's best to check this in an `AuthStateChanged` handler (see the link) - but it seems to work for me usually without this.

Comment: In my own testing, I do find that calling SignInAnonymouslyAsync will generate new users (if you check your authentication dashboard). Anonymous really is anonymous here (the account only persists as long as you don't sign in again). If the user is not signed in, it can be beneficial to create an anonymous account then join it with a more permanent one later - but in the Unity SDK it's not currently possible to recover the anonymous data if linking accounts fails (for example - the user already has a Facebook account registered in your game).